# Python: chain an exception to a warning

Tags: python-3.x, exception, warnings

I want to handle certain exceptions by catching the exception and issuing a warning. When the warning is displayed (e.g. on stderr or in a log file, I use the logging module for that) I want it to display the stack trace of the warning followed by "caused by" plus the stack trace of the original exception.

If I were to raise another exception I would use the `from` keyword (assume `XException`, `YException` are custom exception classes derived from `Exception` and `YWarning` is derived from the `Warning` class):

```py
def do_x():
    riase XException("Failed to do X")

def do_y():
    try:
        # do other things
        do_x()
        # maybe do some more things
    except XException as x_exc:
        raise YException("Failed to do Y") from x_exc
```

But in my case, if doing X fails, it's not such a big deal and I can continue to do Y. I want to issue a warning though.

```py
from warnings import warn

def do_x():
    raise XException("Failed to do X")

def do_y():
    try:
        # do other things
        do_x() # if this fails, we can live with it
    except XException as x_exc:
        warn(YWarning("Things went not so smooth with doing Y", cause=x_exc))
```

Here I made up the `cause=` optional argument, so what I'd like to know is how do I instantiate any Exception subclass (which includes Warning and its subclasses) and specify the cause.

Answer (score 0):

So while writing this question I came up with a possible answer.

```
ywarn = YWarning("Things went not so smooth with doing Y")
ywarn.__cause__ = x_exc
warn(ywarn)
```

It turns out, according to [PEP 3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/#explicit-exception-chaining), that `from` does exactly that.

One could even actually implement the imaginary `cause=` optional argument. After all, the `YWarning` is a custom subclass.

```
class YWarning(Warning):
    def __init__(self, msg, cause=None):
        self.__cause__ = cause
```